# what is the purpose of this bottle and what industry/sector is it aimed at

Tags: ibotta

In reference to the patent: [US7036684](https://www.google.com/patents/US7036684)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Could you explain what you mean by "purpose?" I think your question is a bit on the fence, for whether it's something we'll be able to help with. If you're asking us to interpret the claims and help you to understand what this patent covers, we can do that. But if you're looking for a higher level overview of how it might be used in the real world *beyond that*, I fear that falls outside of our scope. Could you [edit] your question to clarify what you'd like us to help with, specifically? Also, I'll welcome to you check out our [help/on-topic] while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with Description one of the intended use is:-

> The function of displaying ingredients for marketing purposes, as well
>   as the containment and dispersal of the ingredients is thus met in a
>   simple unified bottle design achieving great functional and aesthetic
>   appeal.

Simple google search states it has to be used in food industry, sauce bottle, Jams and like